# Angular 7 parameter route is overriding non parameter route

Tags: angular, routes, angular7

I am using modular structure for my project.

Parent route is

```
 { path: 'questions', loadChildren: '../questions/questions.module#QuestionsModule'}
```

and in child I have :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: QuestionComponent,
children: [
  {
     path: ':id',
     component: ViewComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'ask',
    component: AskComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo:'/:id',
    pathMatch:'full'
 },
]}];
```

for both http://localhost:4200/questions/123 and http://localhost:4200/questions/ask routes , 
ViewComponent is loading.

Here is my folder structure with routing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjd9u9

Comment: how you are redirecting?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar <a [routerLink]="['/questions',123]">Test</a> for route with paramter

routerLink="/questions/ask" is for non paramter route (ask route)

Comment: Did u put router-outlet in questions component?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Yes

Comment: add  your code in stackblitz, with that any one can solve your problem, because nothing wrong in your code provided above)

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Ok i will add , thank you

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Here is stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjd9u9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the routes in your Questions routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: QuestionComponent,
children: [
  {
     path: ':id',
     component: ViewComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'ask',
    component: AskComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo:'/:id',
    pathMatch:'full'
 },
]}];
```

`:id` is just a slot in the path to hold a route parameter.

When you navigate to `http://localhost:4200/questions/ask`, you end up with the following situation:

`:id === 'ask'`

Now, looking at the first path:

```
{
  path: ':id',
  component: ViewComponent,
}
```

The router finds a match using `:id === 'ask'` and therefore renders `ViewComponent`.

To fix this, you can change your routes to the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: QuestionComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'ask', component: AskComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: ViewComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/questions/:id', pathMatch: 'full' }
 }
]}];
```

Comment: Yeh your code fixed the issue, so the issue is with order of routes, Thank You ! learnt new thing :)

Comment: Good to hear. The last path will cause problems though for routes such as http://localhost:4200/questions. The redirect should point to a static route, such as the 'ask' route, or something else like an error page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Routing, add static link before parameter will solves your issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkpabq?file=src/app/pages/index/index.component.html

```
  {
        path: '',
        component: QuestionComponent,
        children: [
          {
             path: 'test/:id',
             component: ViewComponent
          },



   {
        path: 'ask',
        component: AskComponent,
        pathMatch:'full'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo:'/:id',
        pathMatch:'full'
     }


    <div>
    <div>
        <a [routerLink]="['/questions/test',123]">View Questiion </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a [routerLink]="['/questions/ask']">Ask Questiion</a>
    <span style="color:red">It is redirecting to View Question Page : Issue</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering,Yeah, but in address bar it will be displayed as  /questions/test/123 :( 

i wanted /questions/123 this same as stackoverflow site

Comment: Changes view route to :id/:id  
in routerLink="/question//123/what-is-angular"

for now